# My mail server is sending a lot of spam using my domain

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam

A lot of spam is being sent through my mail server. the spams are using alias that don't belong to the registered users. the **mailq** command  output show message like these:

> 487A1600698C2     1901 Fri Jan 27 09:35:15 
>   desarae_leclerc@mydomain.com (host
>   mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79] said: 421 4.7.0 [TSS04]
>   Messages from www.xxx.yyy.zzz temporarily deferred due to user
>   complaints - 4.16.55.1; see
>   https://help.yahoo.com/kb/postmaster/SLN3434.html (in reply to MAIL
>   FROM command))
>                                            h.anseur@yahoo.fr
>
> 491A4600698AE     1265 Fri Jan 27 09:36:43  www-data@mail.mydomain.com
>   (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with
>   mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.36] while sending RCPT TO)
>                                            ejbmarine_chik20@yahoo.com
>
> 4888D600698B9     1280 Fri Jan 27 09:34:58  www-data@mail.mydomain.com
>   (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with
>   mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.36] while sending RCPT TO)
>                                            tiff549@yahoo.com

As you can see, even the user www-data is sending spam. I run the command **postsuper -d ALL** to delete all queue emails but this also include the valid ones.

I use /etc/postfix/sender_access to blacklist all alias or unauthorized senders, actually the file has over 8000 entries

This is the output of **postconf -n** command

> alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
>  alias_maps =
>   hash:/etc/aliases
>  append_dot_mydomain = no
>  biff = no
>   broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
>  config_directory = /etc/postfix
>   content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
>   disable_vrfy_command = no
>  inet_interfaces = all
>   mailbox_size_limit = 0
>  mydestination = mail,
>   localhost.localdomain, localhost
>  myhostname =
>   mail.mydomain.com
>  mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
>   [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24 172.16.16.0/24
>  readme_directory = no
>   recipient_delimiter = +
>  smtp_tls_session_cache_database =
>   btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
>  smtpd_banner = mydomain.com
>   Microsoft Exchange Server 2003
>  smtpd_client_restrictions =
>   reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client
>   sbl.spamhaus.org,
>  smtpd_data_restrictions =
>   reject_multi_recipient_bounce,reject_unauth_pipelining
>   smtpd_helo_required = yes
>  smtpd_helo_restrictions =
>   permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_invalid_helo_hostname,reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
>   smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access
>   hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
>   permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,check_policy_service
>   inet:127.0.0.1:10023
>  smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
>   smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
>  smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
>   smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
>  smtpd_sasl_type =
>   dovecot
>  smtpd_sender_restrictions =
>   hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,check_sender_access
>   hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,permit_mynetworks,
>   reject_sender_login_mismatch,reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_non_fqdn_sender,permit_sasl_authenticated
>   smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
>   smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
>   smtpd_tls_session_cache_database =
>   btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
>  smtpd_use_tls = yes
>   virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-alias-maps.cf
>   virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
>  virtual_mailbox_base = /
>   virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain.com
>  virtual_mailbox_maps =
>   ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-mailbox-maps.cf
>  virtual_minimum_uid =
>   100
>  virtual_uid_maps = static:5000

I need help to stop these spams, please

a sample of /var/log/mail.log

```
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail postfix/pickup[1960]: 312676037EE39: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail postfix/cleanup[64497]: 312676037EE39: message-id=<20170129203322.312676037EE39@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail postfix/qmgr[60188]: 312676037EE39: from=<www-data@mail.mydomain.com>, size=783, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<validuser>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=2213, secured, session=<MjoQnEFH3AB/AAAB>
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail dovecot: imap(validuser): Disconnected: Logged out in=93 out=837
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail postfix/pickup[1960]: 4DBEB6037EE3A: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail postfix/cleanup[61997]: 4DBEB6037EE3A: message-id=<20170129203322.4DBEB6037EE3A@mail.mydomain.com>
Jan 29 16:33:22 mail postfix/qmgr[60188]: 4DBEB6037EE3A: from=<www-data@mail.mydomain.com>, size=844, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

I'm using debian 7, installed maldet
I run the command **maldet -m /usr/local/** and it returns:

```
Linux Malware Detect v1.5
            (C) 2002-2016, R-fx Networks <proj@rfxn.com>
            (C) 2016, Ryan MacDonald <ryan@rfxn.com>
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL v2

maldet(13019): {mon} existing inotify process detected (try -k): 53745
```

But I don't know how use this information for detect a malicious script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: Look up the message IDs in your mail logs to find out more information, such as where the messages came from.

Comment: a sample of /var/log/mail.log

Comment: Right, those messages originated with your web application, so it looks like it's been compromised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution

The first big step towards a definitive solution occurred when the apache2 service was stopped, the sending of the spam mails also stopped, that is to say that the mails were being sent from a script of php.

The following step was to add the following lines to php.ini

```
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = /var/log/phpmail.log
```

This page help me: https://blog.rimuhosting.com/2012/09/20/finding-spam-sending-scripts-on-your-server/

Assign the var/log/phpmail.log file to the user and group www-data

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/log/phpmail.log
chown -R www-data /var/log/phpmail.log
```

When restarting the apache2 service the spams returned, but this time they were registered in the file /var/log/phpmail.log

Stop the apache2 service and look in /var/log/phpmail.log for the spam-causing scripts, they were php files that were marked as php.suspected in a wordpress folder on the apache server (/var/www/). Delete all those files and since I was not using that wordpress folder, I gave it the 440 permission to remain as read only.

Restart the service apache2 and the spam disappeared definitively.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me and has some additional debugging steps.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if www-data is sending SPAM this means that your web server has been compromised.

You should immediately stop your web server and check it for unwanted scripts and backdoors used to send SPAM.

You could use maldet (https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) to find suspicious files.

Or use this approach: https://blog.rimuhosting.com/2012/09/20/finding-spam-sending-scripts-on-your-server/

If you want to be real save, check your database too or make a fresh installation.